# Remove query item from router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-router

I'm using `replace` in vue to add `query` to the current url .
and i assigned `undefined` if the value is not there.

```js
this.$router.replace({
  name: "admin-frs",
  query: {
    limit: this.pageSize,
    page: this.currentPage,
    sort: this.sortbyapi || undefined,
    language: this.sortbyapiLang || undefined,
  },
})
```

this makes the query item disappear from the URL when the query data is getting updated which is fine.

it does not remove it from the query object.

any idea if there's a better approach than this?

plus  is it possible to get the query as it is from the route? like `&limit=10...etc`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for here. Something like this? `/admin-frs?limit=3&page=1&sort=asc&language=fr` Remove what from the query object, also what does it mean?

Comment: Can you clarify: "...and I assigned undefined" if the value is not there.  Assigned undefined to what? What value is not there? Then  "...it does not remove it from the query object"  What does not remove what?

Comment: @kissu lets say if `this.sortbyapi` is empty the `sort` in the `query` object` should disappear from the url and from the object

Comment: @danh I mean look at the assigned values in `query` object .. if one of them is empty i wanted to remove the key from the query. instead of returning `undefined` . my English is bad sorry I m trying my best to explain my problem.

Comment: I got your "problem". Let me try to see if I can find a _pretty_ solution to this.

Comment: Nevermind, I did not get it. `undefined` is working fine, it is removing the query itself from the URL if it's falsy. This is working great as is from the looks of this video: https://i.imgur.com/tR2LSpy.mp4

Comment: @kissu yes this trick works for the url only .. but try to console log the `query` object. then key is still there as undefined. this is not what I'm aiming for only. the answer from @danh handled it pretty well

Comment: Oh, so the question was more about how to remove a key-value pair in an object if the value is falsy. Hence, with something like `pickBy` by lodash: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#pickBy Or in a hand-made way like the given answer. The router was pretty useless in the story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the OP wishes to manipulate the query object passed to `router.replace`.  It can be done with standard js.

Start by explicitly naming a query variable...

```
let query = $router.query;
```

To remove something, use js delete operator. For example, to remove query.limit...

```
// remove the limit
if (!this.pageSize) delete query.limit;
```

Or, if you're building that query, don't put limit in in the first place...

```
let query = {};
if (this.pageSize) query.limit = this.pageSize;
if (this.currentPage) query.page = this.currentPage;
// etc for the other properties
// query will now only have props for those selected above
```

Do any of these manipulations, then pass to the router referring to the variable...

```
$router.replace({ name: "admin-frs", query });
```

To restate as a string, there are probably several methods, including many in libraries you might have around, but natively...

```
let params = [];
for (let key in query)
  params.push(`${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(query[key])}`);
const queryString = params.join("&");
```

Comment: Not even sure why OP is asking this since it's already the default behavior and nothing needs to be done on top of it.

Comment: @kissu, I think that's what the OP needed to understand: that the router api doesn't concern itself with the manipulation of the query data, it just wants an object, and it's up to the caller and standard js to do the work.